# How can I get the edited values corresponding to the keys of a dictionary in views.py POST method, passed as a context variable in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I'm basically trying to develope a Sudoku Solver in Django, and in template I have created a table of 9X9 having the empty cells initially. I want the users to edit those cells and generate a puzzle and submit.
And I want to read that puzzle on POST method but just couldn't do it after searching a lot. And pardon me if it is so obvious as I've just started learning Django.

**logic.py**

```
global table
table = {}
for i in range(9):
for j in range(9):
    key = 'i'
    key = key + str(i)+str(j)
    table[key]=0
```

**views.py**

```
 from .logic import table
 # Create your views here.

def sudokuf(request):
   title = "Sudoku Puzzle"
   if request.method == 'POST' :
      print(request.POST)  # here I want to read the puzzle data and solve it
return render (request,"sudoku.html",table)
```

**sudoku.html**

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}

    {% include "table.html" %}

    <input type="submit" align="centre" value="Solve">

</form>
```

**table.html**

```
<table class="sudoku" align="center">
     <tr>
         {% if i00 %} 
        <td id="i0_0" class="static">{{i00}}</td>           
     {% else %}
            <td id="i0_0" class="edit"><input id="i00" maxlength="1" autocomplete= "off"></td>
         {% endif %}
         {% if i01 %}           
        <td id="i0_1" class="static">{{i01}}</td>
     {% else %}
    <td id="i0_1" class="edit"><input id="i01" maxlength="1" autocomplete= "off"></td>
         {% endif %}
         {% if i02 %}           
        <td id="i0_2" class="static">{{i02}}</td>
     {% else %}
and so on....
```

But I'm getting the same dictionary as I sent(with all 0s as value), as context variable, after clicking 'Solve'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to actually look in request.POST:

```
if request.method == 'POST' :
    print(request.POST)   # not 'table'
```

But secondly, your form fields do not have `name` attributes, so they won't even be sent in the POST to begin with. You need to add those attributes:

```
<input id="i00" name="i00" maxlength="1" autocomplete= "off"
```

Comment: I had (request.POST) as well. going to look for your second suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I seriously had no idea about this thing and was searching around for alternatives since like ages. And it was just this thing.